# Should I use the MPS IDE to create a DSL?

Tags: ide

I was considering creating an IDE and DSL using JetBrains MPS, but it seems like it might be hard to display the cells correctly and have the user change their values. I haven't even figured out how to make a new style yet. I'm the only one working on this project, so I need opinions on whether or not it is possible for someone with about intermediate skills to create a DSL (at almost the same level of complexity as, say, Java) in about a month.

Comment: Hi user, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can [edit] it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

Comment: I’m afraid I can’t edit this question to fit the guidelines. Could you please delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use the Grammar cells that come in the MPS extensions:
https://jetbrains.github.io/MPS-extensions/#grammar-cells-migration

I will suggest you to join the Slack Community of MPS, the community is very helpful: http://slack-mps.jetbrains.com/